# Math methods, confused about the Math.ceil() method

Tags: java

I am a beginner at java and have just started learning. I have recently stumbled upon some Math methods in java, one such being `Math.ceil()` method, and I was just wondering if someone could please explain to me what the `Math.ceil()` method does?

Thank You.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double)

Answer (score 0):

The `ceil()` method rounds a number **upwards** to the nearest integer, and returns the result. If the passed argument is an *integer*, the value will *not be rounded*.

Example:
Round a number upward to its nearest integer:
`Math.ceil(1.4)`
The result will be 
`2.0`
which can be converted to an `int` by typecasting.

Comment: It actually returns 2.0 (a double).

Answer (score 0):

It rounds the argument to the next integer higher than equal to the argument. For example

```
Math.ceil(3.4456)
```

will result in

```
4.0
```

whereas

```
Math.ceil(5)
```

returns

```
5.0
```

Comment: `4.0` and `5.0`, you mean

Comment: Thank smarx @smarx